# I was trying to select the next month from the calendar and was unable to do so

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is the code which I was trying to execute.

```
driver.get("https://easemytrip.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("ddate")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("img2")).click();
```

I am unable to click on the next month of the calendar. Here is the HTML code.

```html
<div class="month">
<div id="dvprevious" class="dvnxt" runat="server">
<img id="img2" onclick="return FillcalendarV(03,2017);" alt="Arrow" src="img/left.png"/>
</div>
<div class="month2">Apr 2017</div>
<div class="month3">
<img id="img1" onclick="return FillcalendarV(05,2017);" alt="Arrow" src="img/right.png"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My two work arounds were to force a mouse click on the item location.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(elem).perform();
    action.moveToElement(elem).click().perform();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it takes a second for the calendar popup to get rendered so you need a brief pause. The next problem I ran into is that you apparently can't click the > img because it's blocked by the container DIV. So, I just clicked the container DIV and it worked. The code below works.

```
driver.get("https://easemytrip.com/");
driver.findElement(By.id("ddate")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.month3"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work.

```
    WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.id("dvfarecal"));
    ele1.click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    WebElement ele2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//img[@src='img/right.png']")));

    ele2.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.id("snd_3_10/05/2017"));
    date.click();
```